# How to use more than one Component type (Embedded, Embeddable) in annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, embeddable

I google, but all example only showing me one `Component` in one object, for example:

https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-component-using-annotations-1.html

I want to have two `Component` in one object, for example:

```
public class PhoneNumber {
   // Phone details
   private int areaCode = 0;
   private int phoneNumber = 0;
   private String name = null;
}

public class Person {
   private String firstName = null;
   private String nickName = null;
   private String lastName = null;
   // Multiple phone details
   private PhoneNumber homePhone = null;
   private PhoneNumber mobilePhone = null;
}
```

Hibernate mapping:

```
<class name="Person" table="PERSON">
 <id name="id" column="PERSON_ID">
  <generator class="native"/>
 </id>

 <property name="firstName" column="FIRST_NAME" />
 ...

 <component name="homePhone" class="PhoneNumber">
  <property name="areaCode" column="HOME_AREA_CODE"/>
  <property name="phoneNumber" column="HOME_PHONE_NUMBER"/>
  <property name="name" column="HOME_NAME"/>
 </component>

 <component name="mobilePhone" class="PhoneNumber">
  <property name="areaCode" column="MOBILE_AREA_CODE"/>
  <property name="phoneNumber" column="MOBILE_PHONE_NUMBER"/>
  <property name="name" column="MOBILE_NAME"/>
 </component>
</class>
```

I have two `Component` above, `homePhone` and `mobilePhone`. How to translate above `Hibernate` mapping into `Java` annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Embeddable    
public class PhoneNumber {
 // Phone details
  private int areaCode = 0;
  private int phoneNumber = 0;
   private String name = null;
 }

 public class Person {
   private String firstName = null;
   private String nickName = null;
   private String lastName = null;
   // Multiple phone details
   @Embedded
   @AttributeOverrides({
   @AttributeOverride(name="areaCode",column=@Column(name="HOME_AREA_CODE"),
    @AttributeOverride(name="phoneNumber",column=@Column(name="HOME_PHONE_NUMBER"),
  @AttributeOverride(name="name",column=@Column(name="HOME_NAME")})
   private PhoneNumber homePhone = null;
  @Embedded
  @AttributeOverrides({
  @AttributeOverride(name="areaCode",column=@Column(name="MOBILE_AREA_CODE"),
  @AttributeOverride(name="phoneNumber",column=@Column(name="MOBILE_PHONE_NUMBER"),
  @AttributeOverride(name="name",column=@Column(name="MOBILE_NAME")})
   private PhoneNumber mobilePhone = null;
   }
```

Annotate you Phone class with @Embeddable

As for each phone component the column name differs. Use the @AttributeOverrride and specify the appropriate column name in you owing entity.This will map the component class to different columns.